# D3 path fill is giving weird result

Tags: svg, d3.js

Tried to draw a sinusoid with positive and negative parts in different color using `path` element and `fill` stroke but got a weird/confusing output.

- With 99 points
  [image]
- With 399 points
  [image]

Here's the D3 code:

```
window.onload = function(){

    let xy_values =[];
    let xy_values2 =[];
    
    let len = 99; //Number of points
    let dt = 8*Math.PI/len; //X-Distance between points
    
    for (var i =0; i<len; i++){
        
        let valx = i*dt;
        let valy = Math.sin(valx);
        
        if(valy > 0){ 
            // Positive sine
            xy_values.push( {key: valx, value: valy} );
            xy_values2.push( {key: valx, value: 0.0} );
        }else{
            //Negative sine
            xy_values.push( {key: valx, value: 0.0} );
            xy_values2.push( {key: valx, value: valy} );
        }
        
    }
    
    draw(xy_values, xy_values2);
    
    }
    
function draw(cdata, ddata){
    
    var height=200;
    var width=800;
    
    let svg=d3.select("#container").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    
    walkX = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 30])
        .range([40, width ])
    
    walkY = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([-1, 1])
        .range([height-10, 10])
    

    
    // Add the green regions
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(cdata)
        .attr("fill", "#BFB")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return walkX(d.key) })
            .y(function(d) { return walkY(d.value) })
        );
    
    // Add the red regions    
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(ddata)
        .attr("fill", "#FBB")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return walkX(d.key) })
            .y(function(d) { return walkY(d.value) })
        );
        
        
    // Add scatter points
    svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(ddata)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return walkX(d.key); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return walkY(d.value); } )
      .attr("r", 1.5)
      .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
        
        
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ 0 + "," + 10 + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(walkX));
        
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ 0 + "," + (height-10) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(walkX));
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ 0 + "," + (height/2) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(walkX));
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 35 +","+ 0 +")")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(walkY));
    
}
```

**Questions**

What's causing that incorrect filling/ Tilted filling ?
Is this because of some precision issue ? or is it a glitch in the way `fill` is implemented in D3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because of some precision issue ? or is it a glitch in the way fill is implemented in D3 ?

No, D3 is only used to create your SVG elements in the DOM not render them, the issue is how SVG fills are applied. When applying a fill to a path element, the fill connects the last point of the path with the first, which is why you see that effect. You'll see that the effect you are trying to remove forms line between these two points. The browser in rendering the SVG does not have any instruction to give the fill a different shape.

One option to fix this is to use an area generator rather than a line generator which allows the option to set a baseline.

The D3 area generator creates a path with two y values for every x value (specifying an area to be filled, rather than a path), in this case one at a baseline (y0) and one at a data value (y1):

```
        d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return walkX(d.key) })
        .y1(function(d) { return walkY(d.value) })
        .y0(function() { return walkY(0) })
```

```js
window.onload = function(){

    let xy_values =[];
    let xy_values2 =[];
    
    let len = 99; //Number of points
    let dt = 8*Math.PI/len; //X-Distance between points
    
    for (var i =0; i<len; i++){
        
        let valx = i*dt;
        let valy = Math.sin(valx);
        
        if(valy > 0){ 
            // Positive sine
            xy_values.push( {key: valx, value: valy} );
            xy_values2.push( {key: valx, value: 0.0} );
        }else{
            //Negative sine
            xy_values.push( {key: valx, value: 0.0} );
            xy_values2.push( {key: valx, value: valy} );
        }
        
    }
    
    draw(xy_values, xy_values2);
    
    }
    
function draw(cdata, ddata){
    
    var height=200;
    var width=800;
    
    let svg=d3.select("#container").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    
    walkX = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 30])
        .range([40, width ])
    
    walkY = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([-1, 1])
        .range([height-10, 10])
    

    
    // Add the green regions
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(cdata)
        .attr("fill", "#BFB")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.area()
            .x(function(d) { return walkX(d.key) })
            .y1(function(d) { return walkY(d.value) })
            .y0(function() { return walkY(0) })
        );
    
    // Add the red regions    
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(ddata)
        .attr("fill", "#FBB")
        .attr("stroke", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", d3.area()
            .x(function(d) { return walkX(d.key) })
            .y1(function(d) { return walkY(d.value) })
            .y0(function() { return walkY(0) })
        );
        
        
    // Add scatter points
    svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(ddata)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return walkX(d.key); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return walkY(d.value); } )
      .attr("r", 1.5)
      .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
        
        
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ 0 + "," + 10 + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(walkX));
        
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ 0 + "," + (height-10) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(walkX));
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ 0 + "," + (height/2) + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(walkX));
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 35 +","+ 0 +")")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(walkY));
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Which gives us:

[image]

Comment: Very Interesting. One query : why the tilting does not happen for the upper region (in green) ?

Comment: Because the last point is close enough to zero (or is zero) that the first and last points on the top path have no change or no noticable change in y value: the edge connecting the first and last points nearly overlaps the axis at y=0.

Comment: In that case, if I append a (x_last, 0) point then the `fill` would display correctly. So that’s how `fill` works,  Thank you.